# Error in SQL Syntax using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to use an hibernate query doing `query.uniqueResult()`
my query contains

> from com.classes.Project where NAME='test'

But I get an error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.project project0_ where NAME='test'' at line 1

The full query generated by hibernate is :

> select project0_.PROJECT_ID as PROJECT1_60_, project0_.CL_ID as
>   CL2_60_, project0_.ATTACHMENT_LIST_ID as ATTACHMENT3_60_,
>   project0_.TCL_ID as TCL4_60_, project0_.RL_ID as RL5_60_,
>   project0_.NAME as NAME60_, project0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT7_60_,
>   project0_.LABEL as LABEL60_, project0_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE60_,
>   project0_.CREATED_BY as CREATED10_60_, project0_.CREATED_ON as
>   CREATED11_60_, project0_.LAST_MODIFIED_BY as LAST12_60_,
>   project0_.LAST_MODIFIED_ON as LAST13_60_, project0_.PROJECT_TYPE as
>   PROJECT14_60_, project0_.TA_SERVER_ID as TA15_60_ from
>   squashtmdev.squashtm.project project0_ where NAME='test'

Associated mapping :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 2 ao?t 2016 14:54:16 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.classes.Project" table="project" catalog="squashtmdev">
        <id name="projectId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="PROJECT_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="campaignLibrary" class="com.classes.CampaignLibrary" fetch="select">
            <column name="CL_ID" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="attachmentList" class="com.classes.AttachmentList" fetch="select">
            <column name="ATTACHMENT_LIST_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="testCaseLibrary" class="com.classes.TestCaseLibrary" fetch="select">
            <column name="TCL_ID" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="requirementLibrary" class="com.classes.RequirementLibrary" fetch="select">
            <column name="RL_ID" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="DESCRIPTION" />
        </property>
        <property name="label" type="string">
            <column name="LABEL" />
        </property>
        <property name="active" type="boolean">
            <column name="ACTIVE" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdBy" type="string">
            <column name="CREATED_BY" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdOn" type="timestamp">
            <column name="CREATED_ON" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastModifiedBy" type="string">
            <column name="LAST_MODIFIED_BY" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastModifiedOn" type="timestamp">
            <column name="LAST_MODIFIED_ON" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="projectType" type="char">
            <column name="PROJECT_TYPE" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="taServerId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="TA_SERVER_ID" />
        </property>
        <set name="testCaseLibraryNodes" table="test_case_library_node" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="PROJECT_ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.classes.TestCaseLibraryNode" />
        </set>
        <set name="campaignLibraryNodes" table="campaign_library_node" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="PROJECT_ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.classes.CampaignLibraryNode" />
        </set>
        <set name="projectFilterEntries" table="project_filter_entry" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="PROJECT_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.classes.ProjectFilterEntry" />
        </set>
        <set name="requirementLibraryNodes" table="requirement_library_node" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="PROJECT_ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.classes.RequirementLibraryNode" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: I think the problem is: squashtmdev.squashtm.project, squashtmdev is the db, squashtm is the table, what is .project ?

Comment: squashtm is the db im sending the query to, project is the table and squashtmdev is the db I used to generate the hibernate classes (I had the same issue generating with the database squashtm, they both have the same data model)

Comment: Is this `from com.classes.Project where NAME='test'` the exact query you're using? With 'test' being a variable?

Comment: @GoZ did you try striping off squashtmdev and executing it in MySQL console?

Comment: No, it's the result of "from "+Project.class.getName()+" where name='"+projectName+"'",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed my problem :

1 - Remove the catalog on the hbm files by using the `hibernate.default_catalog` property in the configuration file and regenerating the classes.

2 - Then if it didn't work and the error is now `could not find the table yourDatabase.yourTable` or using HQL editor `yourDatabase.yourTable is not mapped` try to remove the `table="yourTable"` in the concerned hbm file

I'am not sure about why I had to do that,
I hope it will help